# How can I change the settings for my running instance of redshift?

Tags: screen, brightness, redshift

I have redshift-gtk running happily in my system tray. I want to create some keyboard shortcuts to change the brightness setting for redshift.

I can change the brightness if I just open a terminal and type:

```
redshift -b 0.3
```

OR

```
redshift-gtk -b 0.3
```

But this opens a new instance of redshift, and its brightness setting is overridden by the other instance that's already running.

How do I update the brightness for the running instance of redshift, and have that setting persist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like redshift doesn't yet support changing the current settings, see this [github pull request](https://github.com/jonls/redshift/pull/96). I would sugest a set of scripts tied to keybinding's.

To find and kill running redshift instances run `kill $(ps aux | grep '[r]edshift*' | awk '{print $2}')`.

Your script could change the `~/.config/redshift.conf` file and then restart redshift. Or just run `redshift -b 0.3`

For guidance on changing the config file see [Redshift Ubuntu wiki entry](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Redshift). which includes a example config file.